# Authorize.Net CIM trying to create a profile and do a transaction one after the other

Tags: php, xml, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I am using John Conde's [AuthnetXML](https://github.com/stymiee/Authorize.Net-XML) class he made for Authorize.Net. I am trying to create a `profileID` and a `paymentprofileid` for a user using `createCustomerProfileRequest` and then if created I apply the newly created `customerprofileid` and `customerpaymentprofileid` to the `createCustomerProfileTransactionRequest` and try and put a transaction through.

When it first goes through The account is created but the page goes white like something broke, I then click <kbd>f5</kbd> to push through and it goes through fine. The way it is build is if the user has the ids already I bypass part one. ( creating the profiles ) I feel like it wont let me to two calls to the api one after the other or maybe the account needs a minute to propagate on the server?

Has anyone encountered something like this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen anything like this. I whipped up an example that more or less did what you're trying to do and didn't experience any issues so I posted here for you to compare to your code. Hopefully it is helpful for you:

```
<?php

    require('../../config.inc.php');
    require('../../AuthnetXML.class.php');

    $xml = new AuthnetXML(AUTHNET_LOGIN, AUTHNET_TRANSKEY, AuthnetXML::USE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER);
    $xml->createCustomerProfileRequest(array(
        'profile' => array(
            'merchantCustomerId' => '87658',
            'email' => 'user@example.com',
            'paymentProfiles' => array(
                'billTo' => array(
                    'firstName' => 'John',
                    'lastName' => 'Smith',
                    'address' => '123 Main Street',
                    'city' => 'Townsville',
                    'state' => 'NJ',
                    'zip' => '12345',
                    'phoneNumber' => '800-555-1234'
                ),
                'payment' => array(
                    'creditCard' => array(
                    'cardNumber' => '4111111111111111',
                    'expirationDate' => '2016-08',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'shipToList' => array(
                'firstName' => 'John',
                'lastName' => 'Smith',
                'address' => '123 Main Street',
                'city' => 'Townsville',
                'state' => 'NJ',
                'zip' => '12345',
                'phoneNumber' => '800-555-1234'
            ),
        ),
        'validationMode' => 'liveMode'
    ));

    $profile_id          = $xml->customerProfileId;
    $payment_profile_id  = $xml->customerPaymentProfileIdList->numericString;
    $shipping_profile_id = $xml->customerShippingAddressIdList->numericString;

    $xml = new AuthnetXML(AUTHNET_LOGIN, AUTHNET_TRANSKEY, AuthnetXML::USE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER);
    $xml->createCustomerProfileTransactionRequest(array(
        'transaction' => array(
            'profileTransAuthCapture' => array(
                'amount' => '10.95',
                'customerProfileId' => $profile_id,
                'customerPaymentProfileId' => $payment_profile_id,
                'customerShippingAddressId' => $shipping_profile_id,
                'order' => array(
                    'invoiceNumber' => 'INV000001',
                    'description' => 'description of transaction',
                    'purchaseOrderNumber' => 'PONUM000001'
                ),
                'taxExempt' => 'false',
                'recurringBilling' => 'false',
                'cardCode' => '000'
            )
        ),
        'extraOptions' => '<![CDATA[x_customer_ip=100.0.0.1]]>'
    ));

    echo $xml;
?>
```

Here's the XML that was sent back and forth:

**createCustomerProfileRequest**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<createCustomerProfileRequest>
  <merchantAuthentication>
    <name>cnpdev4289</name>
    <transactionKey>SR2P8g4jdEn7vFLQ</transactionKey>
  </merchantAuthentication>
  <profile>
    <merchantCustomerId>87658</merchantCustomerId>
    <email>user@example.com</email>
    <paymentProfiles>
      <billTo>
        <firstName>John</firstName>
        <lastName>Smith</lastName>
        <address>123 Main Street</address>
        <city>Townsville</city>
        <state>NJ</state>
        <zip>12345</zip>
        <phoneNumber>800-555-1234</phoneNumber>
      </billTo>
      <payment>
        <creditCard>
          <cardNumber>4111111111111111</cardNumber>
          <expirationDate>2016-08</expirationDate>
        </creditCard>
      </payment>
    </paymentProfiles>
    <shipToList>
      <firstName>John</firstName>
      <lastName>Smith</lastName>
      <address>123 Main Street</address>
      <city>Townsville</city>
      <state>NJ</state>
      <zip>12345</zip>
      <phoneNumber>800-555-1234</phoneNumber>
    </shipToList>
  </profile>
  <validationMode>liveMode</validationMode>
</createCustomerProfileRequest>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<createCustomerProfileResponse>
  <messages>
    <resultCode>Ok</resultCode>
    <message>
      <code>I00001</code>
      <text>Successful.</text>
    </message>
  </messages>
  <customerProfileId>11234435</customerProfileId>
  <customerPaymentProfileIdList>
    <numericString>10232106</numericString>
  </customerPaymentProfileIdList>
  <customerShippingAddressIdList>
    <numericString>10454653</numericString>
  </customerShippingAddressIdList>
  <validationDirectResponseList>
    <string>1,1,1,This transaction has been approved.,0ZSYP6,Y,2180917446,none,Test transaction for ValidateCustomerPaymentProfile.,0.00,CC,auth_only,87658,John,Smith,,123 Main Street,Townsville,NJ,12345,,800-555-1234,,user@example.com,,,,,,,,,0.00,0.00,0.00,FALSE,none,CE4F0E75B0703C40FE109A7B0B2E0575,,2,,,,,,,,,,,XXXX1111,Visa,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,</string>
  </validationDirectResponseList>
</createCustomerProfileResponse>
```

**createCustomerProfileTransactionRequest**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<createCustomerProfileTransactionRequest>
  <merchantAuthentication>
    <name>cnpdev4289</name>
    <transactionKey>SR2P8g4jdEn7vFLQ</transactionKey>
  </merchantAuthentication>
  <transaction>
    <profileTransAuthCapture>
      <amount>10.95</amount>
      <customerProfileId>11234435</customerProfileId>
      <customerPaymentProfileId>10232106</customerPaymentProfileId>
      <customerShippingAddressId>10454653</customerShippingAddressId>
      <order>
        <invoiceNumber>INV000001</invoiceNumber>
        <description>description of transaction</description>
        <purchaseOrderNumber>PONUM000001</purchaseOrderNumber>
      </order>
      <taxExempt>false</taxExempt>
      <recurringBilling>false</recurringBilling>
      <cardCode>000</cardCode>
    </profileTransAuthCapture>
  </transaction>
  <extraOptions>&lt;![CDATA[x_customer_ip=100.0.0.1]]&gt;</extraOptions>
</createCustomerProfileTransactionRequest>  

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<createCustomerProfileTransactionResponse>
  <messages>
    <resultCode>Ok</resultCode>
    <message>
      <code>I00001</code>
      <text>Successful.</text>
    </message>
  </messages>
  <directResponse>1,1,1,This transaction has been approved.,S6HDI6,Y,2180917449,INV000001,description of transaction,10.95,CC,auth_capture,87658,John,Smith,,123 Main Street,Townsville,NJ,12345,,800-555-1234,,user@example.com,John,Smith,,123 Main Street,Townsville,NJ,12345,,,,,FALSE,PONUM000001,F0FA82F73AA206A4D7D956E98AF97725,P,2,,,,,,,,,,,XXXX1111,Visa,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,10454653,100.0.0.1]]&gt;</directResponse>
</createCustomerProfileTransactionResponse>
```

Comment: Thank you John for taking the time to do this. I got it to this point today by creating the AuthnetXML object in between as you did it. I thought this might be wrong so I am glad you posted it. I appreciate you putting the time into the class as well and I am sure a lot of other people do too.